# ¿Por qué mi valor booleano cambia solo?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en angular y tengo un problema con el valor de una variable.
Tengo un objeto con un atributo booleano, que se define como un checkbox en la parte html tal que :

```
 <div class="col-md-1">
    <input #myInputPhone type="checkbox"  class="form-control" formControlName="active" [formControl]="valForm.controls['active']">
 </div>
```

He estado depurando y para ver qué valores provienen del componente, y para ello he creado esta línea en el método de envío.

```
if(this.valForm.controls['active'].value == true)
{
  console.log('CHECKBOX MARCADO');
  this.customPoke.active=true;
  console.log('this.customPoke');
  console.log(this.customPoke.active);

}

  this.doAdd(this.customPoke);
```

Aquí el método doAdd :

```
doAdd(value) {

    this.resetFields('Añadiendo un usuario nuevo');


    console.log('this.customPoke doAdd');
    console.log(this.customPoke.active);
    this.pokayokesConfigService.add(this.customPoke).
      subscribe(
        data => {
          this.loadPokayokes();
          this.toasterService.popSuccess('common.messages.addSuccess');
        },
        err => {
          this.onError(err);
        });
  }
```

Y ahora, como podeis ver, estoy marcando el checkbox en el formulario y verificando los valores en la consola.

[Checkbox marcado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7qwj.png)

[Console info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQkpT.png)

Pero el problema es que una vez que inicia el método this.doAdd (), tengo otro registro para ver el objeto completo y el valor del atributo activo y está bien, pero el método doAdd llama al servicio, cuando también estoy registrando el elemento I para ver el objeto completo y el valor del atributo activo cambia.

```
add(type: PokayokesConfig): Observable<PokayokesConfig> {

  console.log('objeto que llega al add: ');
  console.log(type);

  if(type.dateLastSupervision)
  {
    type.dateLastSupervision = new Date();

  }   

  return this.apiService.post(this.baseRoute, type);
}
```

Y como puede ver, en [la consola, muestra el elemento con activo = falso]. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NerOc.png)

Para su información, esta es la clase PokayokesConfig.

```
export class PokayokesConfig extends BaseModel<number> {

  id: number;
  active: boolean;
  codeEnabled: string;
  codeDisabled: string;
  codeSupervision: string;
  name: string;
  messageEnabled: string;
  messageDisabled: string;
  messageSupervision: string;
  localization: string;
  actualState: string;
  actualSuvervisionState: string;
  dateLastSupervision : Date;
}
```

¿Por qué puede estar pasando esto?

Comment: Prueba a cambiar la línea `console.log(type);` por `console.log(JSON.stringify(type, null, 2));` y mira qué sale en la consola, es posible que el navegador te esté *troleando*

Comment: yo probaria crear un customPoke$=new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false) para que todos los componente que lo requieran puedan escuchar o actualizar el estado sin problemas -->https://www.coditty.com/code/how-to-return-boolean-from-observable-using-behaviorsubject